# Concatenating list with nested list

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [[5,6], [7,8]]
c = list(zip(a, b))
print("c zipped:", c)
i = 0
lenghta = len(a)
c = []
while i < lengtha:
    temp_list = [a[i], b[i]]
    c.append(temp_list)
    i += 1
print("c: ", c)
```

output:

```
c zipped: [(1, [5, 6]), (2, [7, 8])] c:  [[1, [5, 6]], [2, [7, 8]]]
```

What I am expecting is:

```
[[1, 5, 6], [2, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems overcomplicated. Try this, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [[5,6], [7,8]]

c = [[x] + b[i] for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't using `zip()`, but you could do:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append([a[i], b[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and `list comprehension`

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [[5,6], [7,8]]

[[i]+j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
#[[1, 5, 6], [2, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: I had a work around using flattening of lists for each row. But I felt that is lot of code. The answers provided by many of you are simple and Pythonic. Feel better now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can also use itertools.chain

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [[5,6], [7,8]]
>>> c = [list(chain([x], y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
>>> c
[[1, 5, 6], [2, 7, 8]]
```